# Body file is unreachable error when upload a file to firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, firebase-storage

```
NSString *filetotest=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/"];
NSString *filessss=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/100445.jpg"];

// File located on disk
NSURL *localFile = [NSURL URLWithString:filessss];

[@"100445.jpg" writeToFile:filetotest atomically:YES];


// Get a reference to the storage service using the default Firebase App
FIRStorage *storage = [FIRStorage storage];

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
FIRStorageReference *storageRef = [storage referenceForURL:@"gs://gnts-xxxxx.appspot.com"];

// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
FIRStorageReference *riversRef = [storageRef child:@"Test"];

// Upload the file to the path "images/rivers.jpg"
FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [riversRef putFile:localFile metadata:nil completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata *metadata, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    } else {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        NSURL *downloadURL = metadata.downloadURL;
    }
}];
```

Got error

CFURLResourceIsReachable failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme

Body file is unreachable: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/100445.jpg
  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file doesn’t exist."

Comment: Instead of `NSURL *localFile = [NSURL URLWithString:filessss];` , using `NSURL *localFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filessss];`

Answer (score 2):

No, I got the path form this code is changed everytime,

NSString *documentsPath= [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

1.
documentsPath /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7D71C4C4-33F8-4D70-AF1E-AFDEB4634031/Documents

2.
documentsPath /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B47C0C4B-0FA1-4E85-9573-89F2D6389535/Documents

I use this file path statically, that makes this error. 
Now my issue is solved by directly apply the file path, 
Thanks nynohu.

Answer (score 0):

If you load file from local, using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:]`.

```
// File located on disk
NSURL *localFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filessss];
```

Comment: got error  Cannot get file size: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “100445.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/100445.jpg, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/100445.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x168b63d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A203232-06BF-41CB-8456-1F2341C06934/Documents/100445.jpg

Comment: Are you sure that file exists at Path?